# remove a file with corrupted name

Tags: linux, rm, inode

So this happened:

```
$ ls
''$'\342\200''abc2.16.5'
$ ls | od -c
0000000 342 200   a   b   c   2   .   1   6   .   5  \n
$ ls -il
76236897 -rw-rw-r-- 1 mob users 0 Aug 16 17:52 ''$'\342\200''abc2.16.5'
```

How do I delete this file? Here are some things that didn't work:

```
$ rm -i -- *
rm: remove regular file ''$'\342\200''abc2.16.5'? y
rm: cannot remove ''$'\342\200''abc2.16.5': No such file or directory

$ rm ./*
rm: cannot remove './'$'\342\200''abc2.16.5': No such file or directory

$ rm ./<TAB>        # for file name completion
rm: cannot remove './'$'\342\200''abc2.16.5': No such file or directory

$ find . -delete
find: cannot delete './\342\200abc2.16.5': No such file or directory

$ perl -e 'unlink(glob("*")) or die $!'
$ perl -e 'unlink(glob("*2.16.5")) or die $!'
No such file or directory at -e line 1.

$ find . -inum 76236897 -delete
find: cannot delete './\342\200abc2.16.5': No such file or directory

$ rename * xxx ; rm -v xxx
rm: cannot remove 'xxx': No such file or directory
```

Curiously, `truncate * --size 0` works, `cat *` works, `shred *` works

What should I try next? System is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8

Comment: Is deleting the directory containing the file an option?

Comment: Not unless someone knows how to delete a non-empty directory

Comment: `rm -rf` should do that for you.

Comment: `rm -rf` empties a directory first and then deletes it. Sadly, also not working.

Comment: I think you have file system corruption.  Can you boot into read-only mode and run `fsck` on the partition with the undeletable file?

Comment: What kind of filesystem is this? Is it healthy?

Comment: This may not work as I would expect tab completion to take care of it, but have you tried escaping all of the special characters? `rm \'\'\$\\342\\200\'\'abc2.16.5\'`

Answer (score 1):

Since you say `shred` works, I'd like to suggest adding the `-u` argument to shred.

From the man page (`man shred`):

> -u     deallocate and remove file after overwriting

So I would try `shred -n 0 -u *` in the directory containing the file.

Comment: :-(  `shred: ''$'\342\200''abc2.16.5': failed to remove: No such file or directory` . I appreciate the effort though.

Comment: Can you add the output of `ls -l` to the OP? Curious about how the permissions of the file look.

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen and by chance, tried opening the parent directory in Vim. That put me in netrw where I could see the offending "files" (what looked like one corrupt file name in the shell appeared as 3 entries in netrw). Deleting each bad file and exiting Vim did the trick.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The answer is clear to me, @Community.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me quite often over the years. For me, it has typically occurred on a Windows NTFS partition; you are using RHEL, but maybe the same process will help you.

I have never been able to successfully delete the corrupted file, or the parent directory.

I have always had to:

- Backup all files *(minus the directory with the corrupted file)*
- Format the partition
- Restore all files

In the event that formatting the partition is not feasible, and the corrupted file isn't causing any real problem, you can also try the following:

- Put the corrupted file in its own directory

  - copy the corrupted file to a new directory
  - copy all the other good files to a new directory
- Move the directory with the corrupted file to `$TEMP` or someplace where it can be safely ignored
- Put all the other good files back where they were